# Can't Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, GPU Issue

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Ubuntu as my first distro ever, but it will not work.

When I go to install it from my USB a few different things happen. I either get a black screen that keeps blinking, walls of repeating error messages of all kinds, or a combination of the two.

I've tried doing the nomodeset and the other options as well [these did nothing], and I've confirmed the USB works as it installed properly without issue on my laptop.

I believe it's some sort of issue with my graphics card but I have no idea what to do. Please, I just want to use Linux.

Specs: cpu: amd fx-6300, ram: 16gb dual-channel ddr3, mobo: amd 990fxa-ud3, gpu: ati amd radeon hd 7870 (gigabyte), SSD: samsung 850 evo